# Make image fill screen on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I have a layout with a header and a few images as content. I would like when any image is clicked, it expands to fit the screen with a transition. jQuery and JS are fair game. Here is what I have, I just can't get it to work with transition because of the `position` changes. It also should cover the header and doesn't.

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $( "main img" ).click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass("click");
     });
 });
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

header {
  height:25%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}

main {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

main img {
  padding:1em;
  transition:1s;
}

main img.click {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  padding:0;
  transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
</header>
<main>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
</main>
```

Comment: To place it over the header add `top:0;` in the `css` for the images.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("img").click(function() {
        if($(this).width() == "100") {
            $($(this).clone(true)).insertAfter(this);
            $(this).css({"position" : "fixed", "z-index" : "3"});
            $(this).animate({"width" : $(window).width()-32, "height" : $(window).height()-32, "top" : "0px"}, 1000);
        }
        else {
            $(this).animate({"width" : "0px", "height" : "0px", "top" : ((($(window).height()-32)/2)-50)}, 500, function() { 
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

header {
  height:25%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}

main {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

main img {
  padding:1em;
}

main {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  padding:0;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
</header>

<main>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
</main>
```

Comment: Thats good, but I was looking for 2 things different. 1) the animation starts in the original position of the image and 2) the other images don't move.

Comment: @thesecretmaster it'd be a little more tricky to animate lets say the image all the way on the left to fill the screen. (not difficult, but hard to make that animation look pretty in reality) Maybe have the animation start at center of the page?

Comment: @thesecretmaster I edited my answer so the images don't move during animation & the animation consistently begins at center of the page. If you can describe a better idea for the animation,

Comment: Maybe it's be possible to use css3 translations to move it center as it grows.