# CSS transform scale fit to window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have tried lot, but didn't get any proper solution.

**Here is my code:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".zoom-close").on("click", function() {
    $(".zoom-close").toggleClass("transform", 1000);
    $(".img").toggleClass("active", 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.col {
  width: 30%;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 1s
}

.img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img.active {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(2.5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.img.active img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.zoom-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 8px 8px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.zoom-close.transform {
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 18px;
}

.zoom-close.transform .zoom-inner {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.zoom-close.transform .zoom {
  border: 0;
}

.zoom-close.transform .zoom:before {
  width: 2px;
  height: 17px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.zoom-close.transform .zoom:after {
  height: 2px;
  width: 17px;
  top: 9px;
  left: -1px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.zoom {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.zoom:before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.zoom-inner {
  width: 8px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.zoom:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 8px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  top: 4px;
  left: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
    <button class="zoom-close">
      <div class="zoom"><span class="zoom-inner"></span> </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Could anyone help me in the below case:**

`<div class="img">` should be fit in to the window size (100% width), when we click on the `<button class="zoom-close">` with the same transform effect.

*(Please note: CSS transform property is not compulsory but I need the similar effect as it is..)*

Comment: If we scale image width to eindow width, Height will also increase and will result in vertical scroll (since the image size may vary). Is that ok for you

Comment: @Ajith No problem if it scrolling vertically.

Comment: Did this solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864505/make-image-fill-screen-on-click

Comment: @Awais Sorry.. No.. zooming should be started from the size of thumb image. But in this answer it is from size 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the screen sizes like `width` and `height` on `zoom` event

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250"  >

  </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <button class="zoom-close">
      <div class="zoom"><span class="zoom-inner"></span> </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var flag=0;
$(function() {
  $(".zoom-close").on("click", function() {
    $(".zoom-close").toggleClass("transform", 1000);
   // $(".img").toggleClass("active", 1000);
   var height= window.screen.height;
   var width = window.screen.width;

   if(flag == 0){
        $("img").css("width", "15vw");
        $("img").css("height", "15vw");
        flag=1;
   }
   else{
        $("img").css("width", "100vw");
        $("img").css("height", "100vw");
        flag=0;
   }

  });
});
```

Comment: let me know if you need few changes.

Comment: I believe you can also use `100vw`, even in a class and toggle it

Comment: @AjayKumar Sure.. I will check & let you know.

Comment: Couldn't make it work.. can you add a working Snippet for me if possible?

Comment: @AjayKumar Only height works in this fiddle, and lost transform effect. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204928/discussion-between-ajay-kumar-and-vishnu).

Comment: @vishnu if you think this resolved  your issue then mark it resolved.